# Sidekiq, Redis, Rails and Ruby - no implicit conversion of Pathname into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, sidekiq

I am trying to get my sidekiq server and client up and running (using Foreman), but whenever it gets to:

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

The following results:

```
no implicit conversion of Pathname into String
```

Just like that, without `Type Error` preceding it - obviously the stack trace followed (will post if it will help). It says that the problem is in active_support/dependencies.rb (version 5.0.0.1) in the `require` method. Earlier in the stack trace it gets to `boot_system` in sidekiq's cli.rb (version 4.1.2). I am not sure whether this is a known issue with sidekiq or whether I am missing some configuration (I have read through a good number of tutorials on this which include thorough discussion of considerations to make in regarding sidekiq, puma and redis' configs, but to no avail). I am running Ruby 2.3.1 and Rails 5.0.0.1

The sidekiq.yml file includes (I got the error before this file and including it did not solve the issue):

```
development:  
  :concurrency: 5
production:  
  :concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
```

Also, I am really new to posting on stackoverflow (but have made frequent use of it in the past). Any guidance would be great!

Comment: If you're using one, you should include the contents of your sidekiq.yml config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did manage to get my sidekiq up and running with redis. My problem was with one of the worker scripts which had an error in it... It was picking it up in a directory other than app/workers (I placed it in app/temp while I was debugging) - only saw it now in the stack trace: obviously missed it earlier due to looking at a screen too long (the classics). Still was weird that the error message was missing `Type Error` though.